# I've spent (at least) a year in the US

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

1. He'**s spent** (at least) a year in the US.
2. He **spent** (at least) a year in the US.

Which is correct? Is "spend" a stative verb?

Comment: Do you understand the differences between simple past and present perfect? That's all this is.

Comment: Yes. If that's what you want to know, then please edit your question. You're going to get a wide variety of answers, none of which will respond to the context you're asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are grammatically correct.

A rough heuristic for which option to choose is shown below. This is not a rule, just a guideline. Thanks to @gotube for the comment about tenses and @stangdon for clarifications.

- Option 1 is the *present perfect* tense. Use option 1 if he's still in the US. "He's spent at least a year in the US thus far, so he will reach his two-year goal fairly soon."

  - In response to your two examples: a) "He has spent several years in the US" and b) "He's spent at least one winter in the US": these two examples suggest (but do not require) that he's still in the US. You can use this tense no matter where he is now. A reader will probably assume he's still in the US unless given additional context .
- Option 2 is the *past simple* tense. Use option 2 when you're talking a past event. "He spent at least a year in the US back in the sixties, but he would hardly recognize it now."

  - Again, *technically* you can use this tense no matter where he is now, but if you use this tense while he's still in the US, you may get weird looks.

With these two examples, removing the parentheses makes the sentences feel more normal. But if you leave them in, that's probably OK too.

Comment: Just two more questions: a) "He **has spent** *several years* in the US". Does it also suggest that he's still in the US? b) "He'**s spent** at least one winter in the US". Like sentence (1) in the OP, does it also necessarily suggest that he's still in the US?

Comment: I think option 1 is also OK if you're talking about experiences up to this point as they relate to the present; it doesn't literally have to still be ongoing.

Comment: @stangdon agreed. I've edited the answer.